# "I" rule this beautiful country. In addition to that, "I" rule you - do I have to use the same subject?

Tags: grammar

**Example 1**

> **I** rule this beautiful country. In addition to that, **you** are the most precious people I've ever seen.

**Example 2**

> **I** rule this beautiful country. In addition to that, **I** rule you, my precious people.

Which one is correct?
I feel like Example 2 is more correct because it uses the same subject "I."

Comment: This question is unclear. These mean completely different things, and both are "correct" as far as I can see.

Comment: Of course two consecutive sentences don't have to have the same subject! Even so, Example 2 sounds better. People are precious to us because of how we feel about them, not because of what they look like - you can say "He is the tallest man I have ever seen" but not "he is the most precious man I have ever seen".

Comment: It all sounds like pretty poor English. Maybe as the translation of some folk tale...I rule this beautiful country *and you*.

Answer (score 1):

The two examples are both correct. They simply have different meanings.

There is no reason why two consecutive sentences should have the same subject.

The sentence

> You are the most precious people I've ever seen.

Is different in meaning to

> I rule you, my precious people.

But both are correct English, albeit a rather odd context.